# Highcharts gauge is render before the data is fetched by json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, getjson

I have came across a strange problem. i have a [web page](http://openweather.in/localpublish/) with 2 highcharts gauge module and am retrieving the data using json from a php script. the json looks like `[{"PID":"1019","Date":"15-10-2014","Time":"02:52:36","Temperature":"31","Humidity":"65"}]`

1) The problem is, during the very first iteration when the data is retried it isn't reflected at the module. [[IMAGE]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jcut3mb3pseze2/1.jpg?dl=0)
2) During the second iteration of data the data is displayed by the module but there is no color highlight and
3) During the third iteration onwards the module reflects the data with color highlight.

I think the problem is due to the async behavior of json. But i not sure about it, am a newbie to web programming.
My javascript is as following

```
var point, temperature, humidity, pressure, windspeed, winddirection, light, rainfall, elevation, lat, lang, bvolt, bcurrent, svolt, scurrent, temp;
$.getJSON("http://openweather.in/localpublish/livedata.php", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            temperature = parseFloat(data[0].Temperature);
            humidity = parseFloat(data[0].Humidity);
            pressure = parseFloat(data[0].Pressure);
            windspeed = parseFloat(data[0].Windspeed);
            winddirection = parseFloat(data[0].Winddirection);
            light = parseFloat(data[0].Light);
            rainfall = parseFloat(data[0].Rainfall);
            elevation = parseFloat(data[0].Elevation);
            lat = parseFloat(data[0].Lat);
            lang = parseFloat(data[0].Lang);
            bvolt = parseFloat(data[0].Bvolt);
            bcurrent = parseFloat(data[0].Bcurrent);
            svolt = parseFloat(data[0].Svolt);
            scurrent = parseFloat(data[0].Scurrent);
        });

 $(document).ready(function () {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '75%'],
            size: '120%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }        
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: -30,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // The Temperature gauge
    $('#container-temperature').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
                stops: [
            [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.75, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            min: 0,
            max: 50     
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: [parseFloat(temperature)],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' + 
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">°C</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]

    }));

    // The Humidity gauge
    $('#container-humidity').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
                stops: [
            [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.55, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.8, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            min: 0,
            max: 100
            },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Humidity',
            data: [parseFloat(humidity)],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' + 
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">%rh</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%rh'
            }      
        }]
    }));

    // The atmospheric pressure gauge
    $('#container-pressure').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
                stops: [
            [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.55, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            min: 0,
            max: 20
            },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Atmospheric Pressure',
            data: [parseFloat(pressure)],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' + 
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 100 hbar</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'hpa'
            }      
        }]
    }));
        setInterval(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://openweather.in/localpublish/livedata.php", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            temperature = data[0].Temperature;
            humidity = data[0].Humidity;
            pressure = data[0].Pressure;
            windspeed = data[0].Windspeed;
            winddirection = data[0].Winddirection;
            light = data[0].Light;
            rainfall = data[0].Rainfall;
            elevation = data[0].Elevation;
            lat = data[0].Lat;
            lang = data[0].Lang;
            bvolt = data[0].Bvolt;
            bcurrent = data[0].Bcurrent;
            svolt = data[0].Svolt;
            scurrent = data[0].Scurrent;
        });

    point = $('#container-temperature').highcharts().series[0].points[0];    
    point.update(parseFloat(temperature));

    point = $('#container-humidity').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(parseFloat(humidity));

    point = $('#container-pressure').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(parseFloat(pressure));
/*  
    point = $('#container-windspeed').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(windspeed);

    point = $('#container-winddirection').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(winddirection);

    point = $('#container-light').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(light);

    point = $('#container-rainfall').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(rainfall);

    point = $('#container-elevation').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(elevation);

    point = $('#').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
    point.update(humidity);

    temp = bvolt + ' V';
    $('#disp-batteryV').val(temp);

    temp = bcurrent + ' mA';
    $('#disp-batteryC').val(temp);

    temp = svolt + ' V';
    $('#disp-solarV').val(temp);

    temp = scurrent + ' mA';
    $('#disp-solarC').val(temp);
*/    
}, 1*60*1000);  
});
```

Comment: Your chart should be inisialised in the $.getJSON() callback, becasue chart is inisialised before, getting whole data.

Comment: there are two $.getJSON() functions one at the very beginning, and second one in setInterval function. If you look at the image its clear that the json responds before the rendering of charts and this happens only sometimes.

Comment: you can have a look at [link](http://openweather.in/localpublish). I have logged json response to the console.

Comment: Use the getjson then in callback load the new one and in the end, run chart. Setinerval for ajax call is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var point, temperature, humidity, pressure, windspeed, winddirection, light, rainfall, elevation, lat, lang, bvolt, bcurrent, svolt, scurrent, temp;
    $.getJSON("http://openweather.in/localpublish/livedata.php", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                temperature = parseFloat(data[0].Temperature);
                humidity = parseFloat(data[0].Humidity);
                pressure = parseFloat(data[0].Pressure);
                windspeed = parseFloat(data[0].Windspeed);
                winddirection = parseFloat(data[0].Winddirection);
                light = parseFloat(data[0].Light);
                rainfall = parseFloat(data[0].Rainfall);
                elevation = parseFloat(data[0].Elevation);
                lat = parseFloat(data[0].Lat);
                lang = parseFloat(data[0].Lang);
                bvolt = parseFloat(data[0].Bvolt);
                bcurrent = parseFloat(data[0].Bcurrent);
                svolt = parseFloat(data[0].Svolt);
                scurrent = parseFloat(data[0].Scurrent);

        var gaugeOptions = {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
            },

            title: null,

            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '75%'],
                size: '120%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                    innerRadius: '60%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    shape: 'arc'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickPixelInterval: 400,
                tickWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    y: -70
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16
                }        
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        y: -30,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        useHTML: true
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // The Temperature gauge
        $('#container-temperature').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                    stops: [
                [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.75, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                min: 0,
                max: 50     
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: [parseFloat(temperature)],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{y}
' + 
                        '°C'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                }
            }]

        }));

        // The Humidity gauge
        $('#container-humidity').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                    stops: [
                [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.55, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.8, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                min: 0,
                max: 100
                },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Humidity',
                data: [parseFloat(humidity)],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{y:.1f}
' + 
                        '%rh'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '%rh'
                }      
            }]
        }));

        // The atmospheric pressure gauge
        $('#container-pressure').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                    stops: [
                [1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.55, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                min: 0,
                max: 20
                },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Atmospheric Pressure',
                data: [parseFloat(pressure)],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{y:.1f}
' + 
                        '* 100 hbar'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: 'hpa'
                }      
            }]
        }));
            setInterval(function () {

        $.getJSON("http://openweather.in/localpublish/livedata.php", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                temperature = data[0].Temperature;
                humidity = data[0].Humidity;
                pressure = data[0].Pressure;
                windspeed = data[0].Windspeed;
                winddirection = data[0].Winddirection;
                light = data[0].Light;
                rainfall = data[0].Rainfall;
                elevation = data[0].Elevation;
                lat = data[0].Lat;
                lang = data[0].Lang;
                bvolt = data[0].Bvolt;
                bcurrent = data[0].Bcurrent;
                svolt = data[0].Svolt;
                scurrent = data[0].Scurrent;
            });

        point = $('#container-temperature').highcharts().series[0].points[0];    
        point.update(parseFloat(temperature));

        point = $('#container-humidity').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(parseFloat(humidity));

        point = $('#container-pressure').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(parseFloat(pressure));
    /*  
        point = $('#container-windspeed').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(windspeed);

        point = $('#container-winddirection').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(winddirection);

        point = $('#container-light').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(light);

        point = $('#container-rainfall').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(rainfall);

        point = $('#container-elevation').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(elevation);

        point = $('#').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
        point.update(humidity);

        temp = bvolt + ' V';
        $('#disp-batteryV').val(temp);

        temp = bcurrent + ' mA';
        $('#disp-batteryC').val(temp);

        temp = svolt + ' V';
        $('#disp-solarV').val(temp);

        temp = scurrent + ' mA';
        $('#disp-solarC').val(temp);
    */    
    }, 1*60*1000);  
    });
```